# Read n tables in csv file to separate pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv, dataframe

I have a single .csv file with four tables, each a different financial statement four Southwest Airlines from 2001-1986. I know I could separate each table into separate files, but they are initially downloaded as one.

I would like to read each table to its own pandas DataFrame for analysis.Here is a subset of the data:

```
Balance Sheet               
Report Date               12/31/2001    12/31/2000  12/31/1999  12/31/1998
Cash & cash equivalents   2279861       522995      418819      378511
Short-term investments    -             -           -            -
Accounts & other receivables    71283   138070      73448       88799
Inventories of parts...   70561          80564        65152     50035

Income Statement                
Report Date               12/31/2001    12/31/2000  12/31/1999  12/31/1998
Passenger revenues        5378702       5467965     4499360     3963781
Freight revenues          91270         110742      102990      98500
Charter & other           -              -           -           -
Special revenue adjustment  -            -           -           -

Statement of Retained Earnings              
Report Date              12/31/2001    12/31/2000   12/31/1999  12/31/1998
Previous ret earn...     2902007       2385854      2044975     1632115
Cumulative effect of..    -              -            -          -
Three-for-two stock split   117885  -   78076   -
Issuance of common..     52753           75952       45134       10184
```

The tables each have 17 columns, the first the line item description, but varying numbers of rows i.e. the balance sheet is 100 rows whereas the statement of cash flows is 65

### What I've Done

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Lines that separate the various financial statements
lines_to_skip = [0, 102, 103, 158, 159, 169, 170]

with open('LUV.csv', 'r') as file:
    fin_statements = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=lines_to_skip)

balance_sheet = fin_statements[0:100]
```

I have seen posts with a similar objective noting to utilize nrows and skiprows. I utilized skiprows to read the entire file, then I created the individual financial statement by indexing.

I am looking for comments and cconstructive criticism for creating a dataframe for each respective table in better Pythonic style and best practices.

Comment: You already know the line numbers where each table starts?

Comment: whats the delimiter in the csv file? can you post it as raw text?

Comment: you could create function which split this file in separated files and then you can read them normally. It seems you can use empty line to recognize end of table.

Comment: @AMC Yes, I know the line numbers where each starts. This isn't a standard format, it could be different each time I download financials for different companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do if far beyond what `read_csv` can do. If fact you input file struct can be modeled as:

```
REPEAT:
    Dataframe name
    Header line
    REPEAT:
        Data line
   BLANK LINE OR END OF FILE
```

IMHO, the simplest way is to parse the line *by hand* line by line, feeding a temporary csv file per dataframe, then loading the dataframe. Code could be:

```
df = {}        # dictionary of dataframes

def process(tmp, df_name):
'''Process the temporary file corresponding to one dataframe'''                
    # print("Process", df_name, tmp.name)  # uncomment for debugging
    if tmp is not None:
        tmp.close()
        df[df_name] = pd.read_csv(tmp.name)
        os.remove(tmp.name)                # do not forget to remove the temp file

with open('LUV.csv') as file:
    df_name = "NONAME"                     # should never be in resulting dict...
    tmp = None
    for line in file:
        # print(line)                      # uncomment for debugging
        if len(line.strip()) == 0:         # close temp file on empty line
            process(tmp, df_name)          # and process it
            tmp = None
        elif tmp is None:                  # a new part: store the name
            df_name = line.strip()
            state = 1
            tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile("w", delete=False)
        else:
            tmp.write(line)                # just feed the temp file

    # process the last part if no empty line was present...
    process(tmp, df_name)
```

This is not really efficient because each line is written to a temporary file an then read again, but it is simple and robust.

A possible improvement would be to initially parse the parts with the csv module (can parse a stream while pandas wants files). The downside is that the csv module only parse into strings and you lose the automatic conversions to numbers of pandas. My opinion is that it is worth it only if the file is large and the full operation will have to be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:
My assumption is that each statement starts with an indicator ('Balance Sheet', 'Income Statement', 'Statement of Retained Earnings'), we can split the table based on that to get individual dataframes. That is the premise on which the following code is based. let me know if it is a flawed assumption.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#i copied your data above and created a csv with it

df = pd.read_csv('csvtable_stackoverflow',header=None)

        0
0   Balance Sheet
1   Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/...
2   Cash & cash equivalents 2279861 522995...
3   Short-term investments - - ...
4   Accounts & other receivables 71283 138070...
5   Inventories of parts... 70561 80564...
6   Income Statement
7   Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/...
8   Passenger revenues 5378702 546796...
9   Freight revenues 91270 110742...
10  Charter & other - - ...
11  Special revenue adjustment - - ...
12  Statement of Retained Earnings
13  Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/2...
14  Previous ret earn... 2902007 2385854...
15  Cumulative effect of.. - - ...
16  Three-for-two stock split 117885 - 78076 -
17  Issuance of common.. 52753 75952...
```

The code below simply uses numpy select to filter out which rows contain 
balance sheet or income statement or cashflow

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

```
bal_sheet = df[0].str.strip()=='Balance Sheet'
income_stmt = df[0].str.strip()=='Income Statement'
cash_flow_sheet = df[0].str.strip()=='Statement of Retained Earnings'
condlist = [bal_sheet, income_stmt, cash_flow_sheet]
choicelist = ['Balance Sheet', 'Income Statement', 'Statement of 
                                                   Retained Earnings']
```

Next code below creates a column indicating the sheet type, converts '0' to null and then fills down

```
df = (df.assign(sheet_type = np.select(condlist,choicelist))
      .assign(sheet_type = lambda x: x.sheet_type.replace('0',np.nan))
      .fillna(method='ffill')
      )
```

Last step is to pull out the individual dataframes

```
df_bal_sheet = df.copy().query('sheet_type=="Balance Sheet"')
df_income_sheet = df.copy().query('sheet_type=="Income Statement"')
df_cash_flow = df.copy().query('sheet_type=="Statement of Retained Earnings"')

df_bal_sheet :     
         0                                            sheet_type
0   Balance Sheet                                    Balance Sheet
1   Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/...                 Balance Sheet
2   Cash & cash equivalents 2279861 522995...        Balance Sheet
3   Short-term investments - - ...                   Balance Sheet
4   Accounts & other receivables 71283 138070...     Balance Sheet
5   Inventories of parts... 70561 80564...           Balance Sheet

df_income_sheet : 
           0                                     sheet_type
6   Income Statement                           Income Statement
7   Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/...           Income Statement
8   Passenger revenues 5378702 546796...       Income Statement
9   Freight revenues 91270 110742...           Income Statement
10  Charter & other - - ...                    Income Statement
11  Special revenue adjustment - - ...         Income Statement

df_cash_flow:
              0                                         sheet_type
12  Statement of Retained Earnings              Statement of Retained Earnings
13  Report Date 12/31/2001 12/31/2...           Statement of Retained Earnings
14  Previous ret earn... 2902007 2385854...     Statement of Retained Earnings
15  Cumulative effect of.. - - ...              Statement of Retained Earnings
16  Three-for-two stock split 117885 - 78076 -  Statement of Retained Earnings
17  Issuance of common.. 52753 75952...         Statement of Retained Earnings
```

You can do further manipulation by fixing the column names and removing rows you do not need.